# The dist function in my p5.js game project seems to be above 400 even when the character and the collectible are together

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js, translate

I can't get my collectible to disappear when dist is less than 50 in p5.js The dist function in my p5.js game project seems to be above 400 even when the character and the collectible are together.

I tried to anchor the collectible towards it's center by using translate. But even when the collectible is anchored the dist is still above 400, and when i even set the condition to be make the collection is.found = true when distance is less than 500 to make the collectible disappear it seems not to work. I really can't get what am doing wrong.

------ p5.js

```
//COLLECTIBLE
  push();

  collectable = {
    x_pos: 100,
    y_pos: 310,
    size: 40,
    isFound: false,
  };

  translate(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos);
  collectable = {
    x_pos: 0,
    y_pos: 0,
    size: 40,
    isFound: false,
  };

  //distance =
  if (collectable.isFound == false) {
    fill(255, 215, 0);
    ellipse(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos + 100, collectable.size);
    fill(218, 165, 32);
    ellipse(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos + 100, collectable.size - 10);
    fill(255, 215, 0);
    text("£", collectable.x_pos - 5, collectable.y_pos + 107);
    pop();
    textSize(collectable.size - 20);
  }

  distance = dist(collectable.x_pos, collectable.y_pos, gameChar_x, gameChar_y);
  if (distance < 400) {
    collectable.isFound = true;
  }
```

Comment: The collectable.x_pos and collectable.y_pos are both set to 0, so it will never find it's true distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'isFound' property is being overwritten every time this code is called.
Check this: https://editor.p5js.org/Kroepniek/sketches/72le203Hl